# Spring Boot @Cacheable - how to check if object exists in cache without storing it

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have enabled a simple cache in Spring Boot to store objects with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
    ...
}
```

and the component/method

```
@Component
public class MyObjectCache {
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "myObjectCache", key = "#key", sync = true)
    public MyObject findObject(String key) {
        // logic
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

`@Cacheable` wants to store the object if it doesn't exist and requires me to create a new object in the `// logic` section, but I need a way to just check if the object is there since I create it in a set of outer use cases via another `@CachePut` method, which I call when I actually need to store an object.

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "myObjectCache", key = "#myObject.id")
public MyObject update(MyObject obj) {
    // do stuff
    return obj;
}
```

How do I just check for the key/object's existence in the cache without trying to store a new one? This strikes me as a common use case to be supported (in a straightforward way, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I use that works for me:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myObjectCache", key = "#key")
public MyObject findObject(String key, MyObject object) {

    // To see if object is in cache, pass in null for the object
    // with the key you're checking and throw an exception.
    // If the object is already in the cache for the desired key,
    // it will be returned without this method body being executed
    // If not, an exception is thrown here and nothing is saved 
    // for the key in the cache.
    if (object == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object not in cache");
    }

    // I pass the cached object in as the 2nd parameter 
    // and it is placed in cache on initial call
    return myObject;
}
```

Then, just handle the exception in the calling method for the cases when the object is not in the cache.